# Git and Repository URL In Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question: I am learning Jenkins pipeline. I cloned from github and saved it in my local repository, but when I added the local repository URL to Git SCM, I got an error as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Repo url dialog]

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: It doesn't want your local folder in which you clone the repo. It wants to github url of your project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) (I know, who reads that ?), supported syntax is for UNIX-like paths, even on Windows machines.

> **Repository URL** The URL of the remote repository. The git plugin passes the remote repository URL to the git implementation (command
> line or JGit). Valid repository URL’s include https, ssh, scp, git,
> local file, and other forms. Valid repository URL forms are described
> in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_protocols).

**[Allow local checkout](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-allow-local-checkout)**

> Command line git and JGit can fetch a repository using a local URL
> (like `file:/my/repo.git`) or a path (like `/my/repo.git`).

It will interpret "\" as an escape character, but is smart enough to change the path delimiter to the native syntax for Windows.

But why not just let Jenkins pull from GitHub? Best practice is you should be using a separate instance of your repo for local development vs controlled build; that ensures your build uses committed changes and not whatever happens to be present.